# Python class property not changed

Tags: python, class, object, properties

I have this code in my python script

```
class Class(object):
    client_id = ''

    @classmethod
    def get_client_id(cls):
        return cls.client_id


class Service(object):

    @staticmethod
    def get_class():
        cls_obj = Class()
        cls_obj.client_id = 'this is client id'
        return cls_obj

print(Service.get_class().get_client_id())
```

but when i run the python script, it displays empty string
and not the 'this is client id'. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are literally changing the `cls_obj.client_id`, not `cls.client_id`.

Note that you could access the class variable `client_id` with `cls_obj.client_id`, but if you assign to it, you just add an instance variable to `cls_obj`. Now you have both `cls.client_id` and `cls_obj.client_id`, next time you try `cls_obj.client_id` you'll get the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the property on an instance of the class, not the class itself -- that doesn't percolate up to the class or anything. The class method getter however looks on the class, so it doesn't find it. Remove `@classmethod` and it will work.